# Python script for Arduino based accelerometer mouse is not working

Tags: python, arduino

a few days ago I came up with the idea to control the mouse cursor of my Windows 10 PC with an accelerometer and an Arduino Leonardo.

My Arduino setup is as follows: An ADXL335 accelerometer is connected to an Arduino Leonardo, a short Python program is taking some serial input from an Arduino program on the Leonardo and controls the mouse cursor on my Windows 10 PC.

The problem is that the Python is throwing an error (see below).

First of all, the Arduino Code (compiling and upload were successful):

```
const int x=A0;
const int y=A1;
int xh, yh;
int xcord, ycord;

void setup() {
  pinMode(x,INPUT);
  pinMode(y,INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  xh=analogRead(x);
  yh=analogRead(y);
  xcord=map(xh,286,429,100,999);
  ycord=map(yh,282,427,100,800);
  Serial.print(xcord);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(ycord);
  Serial.println();
  delay(4000);
}
```

Now, the Python program:

```
import serial
import pyautogui
ser=serial.Serial('com7',9600)
while 1:
    k=ser.read(8)
    cursor=k[:6]
    x=cursor[:3]
    y=cursor[3:]
    xcor=int(x.decode('UTF-8'))
    ycor=int(y.decode('UTF-8'))
    pyautogui.moveTo(xcor,ycor)
```

And the error:

```
File "C:\Users\User\Downloads\test.py", line 10, in <module>
ycor=int(y.decode('UTF-8'))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '7 3'
```

Have you got any advices? I need your help.

Thank you.

Best wishes,

Michael

Comment: If you have a Leonardo then you don't really need the Python program.  The Leonardo can be a mouse all by itself.  There is even a library for it included in the IDE if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect the values values for `x` and `y` to be included in `k` separated with whitespace, you can do:

```
import serial
import pyautogui
ser=serial.Serial('com7',9600)
while 1:
    k=ser.read(8).decode()
    cursor_list = k.split()
    xcor=int(cursor_list[0])
    ycor=int(cursor_list[1])
    pyautogui.moveTo(xcor,ycor)
```

If there is additional data included in a single read, the indices for `x` and `y` might not be `0` and `1` and you can verify this, by checking documentation for Arduino or printing out `k` during debugging.

Comment: There's another question that bothers me: What are the requirements for a sensor to work with an Arduino? Does each sensor work or do certain connectors/pins/ports need to be present?